# what are the benefits of using webpack directly instead of using angular-cli

Tags: webpack, angular-cli, jhipster, angular5

i am trying to add angular5 to my java project as my front-end framework.
i check Jhipster angular2 project and some angular best practices projects on github.

after crawling on config files on different projects i realize that for example jhipster is using webpack module bundler config files directly but other projects for example([SmartAdmin Dashboard](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-WB0573SK0)) is using angular-cli as default.

the point is angular-cli is using webpack too but it is using angular-cli.json file as a wrapper to handle and simplify webpack configuration.

the question is

1. what are the benefits of using webpack configuration directly instead of angular-cli and what are the differences?
2. which one i have to use in my project?

i searched about this article but i couldn't find a correct answer

Comment: You can see JHipster's discussion over this topic https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/5661 and https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6614

Answer (score 3):

I was also confused about this problem, wasn't using jhipster though. [This](https://1904labs.com/2017/05/06/1399/) article helped me. I hope it will help others. Author has listed following pros and cons of angular-cli

**Pros**

- Extremely quick and easy to setup, ideal for beginners
- Webpack, Protractor e2e testing, Karma/Jasmine testing setup
  automatically
- Dependencies pulled in automatically
- Centralized configuration via an Angular CLI config file
- Quick and easy CLI commands to run the app, create new Components,
  etc…

**Cons**

- Less advanced configuration (cannot change advanced Webpackconfig,
  etc…)
- More rigid configuration structure (harder to move config files to
  desired locations, they’re more strewn about inside of various
  different directories)
- Less or no support for various addons (HTML template engines like
  PugJS, etc…)

The pros and cons really boil down to this: Angular CLI makes the project a lot easier to manage, but also makes the project less
flexible. It’s great for beginners or simple projects, but a manual approach will likely be required if a project calls for more advanced configuration.